# Yii relation — MySQL foreign key

Tags: mysql, yii, relation

Tables in MySQL:

**field:**

```
id pk
```

---

**field_option**

```
id pk

feild_id int(11)    

ALTER TABLE  `field_option` ADD CONSTRAINT  `option_field` FOREIGN KEY (  `feild_id` ) REFERENCES  `agahi_fixed`.`field` (
`id`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

---

Relation  Field model:

```
return array(
  'fieldOption' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'FieldOption', 'feild_id'),
);
```

Relation  FieldOption model:

```
return array(
    'feild' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Field', 'feild_id'),
);
```

In controller:

```
if(Field::model()->exists('cat_id = :catId', array(":catId"=>$_POST['catid']))){
            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
            //$criteria->select='*';  
            $criteria->condition='cat_id=:catId';
            $criteria->params=array(':catId'=>$_POST['catid']);
            $criteria->with = 'fieldOption';
            $field=Field::model()->findAll($criteria);
            header('Content-type: application /json');
            $jsonRows=CJSON::encode($field);
            echo $jsonRows;
        }
```

but it does not work with just select records in field table.

Why?

Comment: Your consistent misspelling (or, unorthodox spelling) of `feild_id` is unusual — it would probably be better as `field_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way you won't achive what your looking for,

when you fetch your records using `with` it will fetch associated records, meaning : `eager loading` not `lazy`, but when you json encode your model, It will get attributes of your main model, not any relations, If you want any related data to get encoded with the model, you have to explicitly say so. I suggest make an empty array :

```
$result = array();
```

make a loop over your model and append to this result, from model to related model

```
foreach($field as $model)
{
  $record = $model->attributes; // get main model attributes
  foreach($model->fieldOption as $relation)
     $record['fieldOption'][] = $relation->attributes; // any related records, must be explicitly declared

  $result[] = $record;
}
```

now you have exactly what you need, then echo it

```
 echo CJSON::encode($result);
```